# Plotting grouped bar plot defined by column

Tags: r

This is a simple bar plot problem but I have difficulties when the grouping is done by columns not by rows. I have a data frame where each column has two values. Im trying to do a bar plot which has each of the values of a column next to one another and then the values of the next column and so on. Also the values from first row should be red and from the second row green.

```
x1 <- c(23.5, 21.8, 13.5, 12.3, 11.1)
x2 <- c(14.5, 23.5, 9.0, 17.5, 6.7)

x3 <- rbind(x1,x2)
x4 <- as.data.frame(x3)
```

So in the picture it should be first values 23.5 and 14.5 then 21.8 and 23.5 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can get you started.

```r
x1 <- c(23.5, 21.8, 13.5, 12.3, 11.1)
x2 <- c(14.5, 23.5, 9.0, 17.5, 6.7)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2))
my_cols = c("red","green")
barplot(t(df),beside=T,ylim=c(0,25), col = my_cols)
```

## Output

[image: sample_output]